# How do we find the solution of the problem in interlaced form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the differnetial equation $$(x-xy(x))+(y(x)+x^2)y'(x)=0$$

I have found the integrating factor $\mu (x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Using this I have to find the solution of the problem in interlaced form.

Could you give me some hints what I am supposed to do?

I got stuck right now...

Multiplying by the integrating factor we get $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x-xy(x))dx+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(y(x)+x^2)dy=0$$ or not?

How could we continue?

$$$$

**EDIT:**

Is it maybe as follows? $$y'=F(y,x) \\ \Rightarrow (x-xy(x))+(y(x)+x^2)F(y,x)=0 \\ \Rightarrow y(x)(1-x)+x^2+x+x^2F(y,x)=0 \\ \Rightarrow y(x)=-\frac{x^2F(y,x)-x-x^2}{1-x}$$

Comment: Please choose a more informative title.

Comment: Multiplying by the integrating factor we get $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(x-xy(x))dx+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}(y(x)+x^2)dy=0$$ or not? How could we continue? @joriki

Comment: Are you sure y is a function of x? That makes this very difficult

Comment: Yes... This is the formula. @TnilkImaniq Is it maybe as follows? $$y'=F(y,x) \\ \Rightarrow (x-xy(x))+(y(x)+x^2)F(y,x)=0 \\ \Rightarrow y(x)(1-x)+x^2+x+x^2F(y,x)=0 \\ \Rightarrow y(x)=-\frac{x^2F(y,x)-x-x^2}{1-x}$$

Comment: No. How can the derivative of a function of x depend on y? The line $y' = F(x,y)$ is incorrect.

Comment: this is an equation of Abel type

Comment: I'm not sure you have found the right integrating factor. Could you perhaps add your derivation of the form of $\mu(x,y)$?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\left(x-xy(x)\right)+\left(y(x)+x^2\right)y'(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(x^2+y(x)\right)y'(x)-y(x)x+x=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $\text{Q}(x,y)=x-xy$ and $\text{T}(x,y)=x^2+y$.

This is not an exact equation, because $\frac{\partial\text{Q}(x,y)}{\partial y}=-x\ne2x=\frac{\partial\text{T}(x,y)}{\partial x}$.

Find an integrating factor $\mu(y)$ such that is exact:

$$\mu(y)\text{Q}(x,y)+\mu\cdot\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}\cdot\text{T}(x,y)=0$$

This means that:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\mu(y)\text{Q}(x,y)\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\mu(y)\text{T}(x,y)\right)$$

---

$$\frac{\text{d}\mu(y)}{\text{d}y}\left(x-yx\right)-\mu(y)x=2x\mu(y)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\mu'(y)}{\mu(y)}=-\frac{3}{y-1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\mu'(y)}{\mu(y)}\space\text{d}y=\int-\frac{3}{y-1}\space\text{d}y\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left(\mu(y)\right)=-3\ln\left(y-1\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mu(y)=\frac{1}{(y-1)^3}$$

---

Let $\text{P}(x,y)=-\frac{x}{(y-1)^2}$ and $\text{R}(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y}{(y-1)^3}$.

This is an exact equation, because $\frac{\partial\text{P}(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{2x}{y-1)^3}=\frac{\partial\text{R}(x,y)}{\partial x}$.

Define $f(x,y)$ such that $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=\text{P}(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\text{R}(x,y)$:

Then, the solution will be given by $f(x,y)=\text{C}$, where $\text{C}$ is an arbitrary constant.

Integrate $\frac{\partial f(,y)}{\partial x}$ to find $f(x,y)$ and where $g(y)$ is an arbitrary function of $y$:

$$f(x,y)=\int-\frac{x}{(y-1)^2}\space\text{d}x=-\frac{x^2}{2(y-1)^2}+g(y)$$

Now, differentiate $f(x,y)$ to find $g(y)$:

$$g'(y)=\frac{y}{(y-1)^3}$$

---

So, in the end you've to solve:

$$-\frac{x^2}{2(y-1)^2}+\frac{1-2y}{2(y-1)^2}=\text{C}$$

Comment: I was asked to find an integratig factor $\mu (x,y)=\phi (x^2+y^2)$ . So, is the one that I found correct?

Comment: @MaryStar You can answer your own question, by solving this first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation and find out if your integrating factor works .... !

Comment: Which first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation do you mean exactly? I got stuck right now...

Comment: @MaryStar I've solved it for you, I hope you can now understand the question and its answer

Comment: In general, I would advise to take @JanEerland's approach, as the resulting integrating factor is easier. However, if a functional form $\mu(x,y) = \phi(x^2+y^2)$ is assumed, then this is what you should do (it's worthwhile to make this assumption explicit in your question, btw!). However, you've made a small mistake calculating $\phi$: it should be $\phi(z) = z^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ instead of $z^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Ah ok... I see... Is my idea at the edit part of my initial post also wrong? @JanEerland

Comment: Ah ok... I see... Is my idea at the edit part of my initial post also wrong? @FritsVeerman

Comment: Well, its usefulness is limited for this question, certainly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I worked this problem. I see that it is similar to Jan Eerland's in several respects, including the integrating factor of $\frac1{(1-y)^3}$. However, I think there may be enough difference to warrant posting.

---

Starting with the equation
$$
(x-xy)+\left(y+x^2\right)y'=0\tag{1}
$$
we want to find an integrating factor $u$ so that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[u(x-xy)\right]=-xu+(x-xy)u_y\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[u\!\left(y+x^2\right)\right]=2xu+\left(y+x^2\right)\!u_x\tag{3}
$$
are equal.

Subtracting $(2)$ and $(3)$ and dividing by $x$ yields
$$
(1-y)u_y=3u+\left(\frac yx+x\right)\!u_x\tag{4}
$$
If we make $u$ dependent only on $y$, then $u_x=0$ and $(4)$ can be solved as
$$
u=\frac1{(1-y)^3}\tag{5}
$$
Therefore, we get the exact differential equation
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\mathrm{d}f=\frac{x}{(1-y)^2}\mathrm{d}x+\frac{y+x^2}{(1-y)^3}\mathrm{d}y=0}\tag{6}
$$
To solve $(6)$ for $f$, we can start by integrating up the $y$-axis, that is $x=0$, to get
$$
\begin{align}
f(0,y)-f(0,0)
&=\int_0^y\frac{t}{(1-t)^3}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac12\frac{y^2}{(1-y)^2}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Then integrate along the $x$-direction to get
$$
\begin{align}
f(x,y)-f(0,0)&=f(0,y)-f(0,0)+\int_0^x\frac{t}{(1-y)^2}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac12\frac{y^2}{(1-y)^2}+\frac12\frac{x^2}{(1-y)^2}\\
&=\frac12\frac{x^2+y^2}{(1-y)^2}\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the solution to $(1)$ is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x^2+y^2}{(1-y)^2}=C}\tag{9}
$$